# Select outer div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select the outer div. My code is currently like this

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner" onClick="selectItem($(this))">

    </div>
</div>
```

So, what I want to do is when the person clicks inner, get the outer div. I've tried this

```
function selectItem(element){
    var outer = element.parentNode;
    console.log(outer);
}
```

but it comes up as undefined. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Is `$`  `jQuery` ?

Answer (score 0):

**JS version:**
modify the onClick call to **onClick="selectItem(this)"**, because you are using **parentNode** property to get the parent, which is only available in native dom object not available in jQuery object.

**jQuery Version:** no need to modify the onClick call in this case. modify selectItem function like below to use jQuery **parent** function to get the parent.

```
function selectItem(element){
    var outer = element.parent().get(0);
    console.log(outer);
}
```

Comment: I want to get it based off the element. As there is going to be multiple outers and inners.

Comment: further clarified. @jnDny